# What is the proper way to read values from Firebase considering the MVC approach?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, closures

I'm quite new to Swift and currently dealing with the Firebase-Database.
I managed to realise the functions that I want to have, but my implementation feels not right.
Most I am struggling with the closures, that I need to get data from Firebase.

I tried to follow the MVC approach and have DataBaseManager, which is getting filling my model:

```
func getCollectionData(user: String, callback: @escaping([CollectionData]) -> Void) {
        
        var dataArray: [CollectionData] = []
        var imageArray:[String] = []
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection(user).getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents : \(err)")
            }
            
            else {
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let album = document.get("album") as! String
                    let artist = document.get("artist") as! String
                    let genre = document.get("genre") as! String
                    let location = document.get("location") as! String
                    var a = CollectionData(album: album, artist: artist, imageArray: imageArray, genre: genre, location: location)
                    a.imageArray!.append(document.get("fronturl") as? String ?? "No Image")
                    a.imageArray!.append(document.get("backurl") as? String ?? "No Image")
                    a.imageArray!.append(document.get("coverlurl") as? String ?? "No Image")
                    
                    dataArray.append(a)
  
                }
                
                callback(dataArray)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

With this I'm getting the information and the downloadlinks, which I later use in a gallery.
Is this the right way?
I feel not, because the fiddling starts, when I fetch the data from my ViewController:

```
var dataArray = []
        dataBaseManager.getCollectionData(user: user) { data in
            self.dataArray = data
```

I can see, that I sometimes run into problems with timing, when I use data from dataArray immediately after running the closure.

My question is, this a valid way to handle the data from Firebase or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking for the proper way, the most elegant way, or a valid way? What's "proper" or "valid" is what works... does this way work for you? What's "elegant" is a matter of opinion and thus off-topic here. See the [help] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, using dataArray *immediately* is where the issue could be.

Let me provide a high level example with some pseudo code as a template:

Suppose you have an ToDo app; the user logs in and the first view they see is all of their current To Do's

```
class viewController
   var dataArray = [ToDo]() //a class property used as a tableViewDataSource
   @IBOutlet toDoTableView

   viewDidLoad {
       loadToDos()
   }

   func loadToDos() {
      thisUsersToDoCollection.getDocuments() { documents in
         self.array.append( the to Do Documents)
         self.toDoTableView.reloadData()
      }
   }
}
```

With the above template you can see that within the Firebase `.getDocuments` function, we get the To Do documents from the colleciton, populate the dataSource array and THEN reload the tableView to display that data.

Following this design pattern will alleviate this issue

> I sometimes run into problems with timing, when I use data from
> dataArray immediately after running the closure

Because the user cannot interact with the data until it's fully loaded and populated within the tableView.

You could of course do a callback within the loadToDos function if you prefer so it would then be called like this - only reload the tableView once the loadToDos function has completed

```
   viewDidLoad {
       loadToDos { 
          toDoTableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
```

The big picture concept here is that Firebase data is ONLY VALID WITHIN THE CLOSURE following the Firebase call. Let that sequence provide pacing to your app; only display info if it's valid, only allow the user to interact with the data when it's actually available.